Different letters, different grids
Given the four grids of letters below, which option 1-5 must replace the question marks?

                   BZCXANQST 
                   QZREJILTS
                   PHOTUKASP
                   ZEGMSRLIY
                   OWRTQCHBU
                   

                   SRAJEKILW
                   KPOMZNDRQ
                   WDUZAREMG
                   KSINTCRFP
                   WNORUGATH

                
                   BKATEMIRG
                   QPKFOLSTN
                   XTWSUPGRY
                   DRTBACNGH  
                   WYEGIMOZG 


                   PAMERIKOJ
                   URTCKFGWA
                   ENTHYBRNI
                   ORSGFDJLU
                   JAZEMINOR


                   ?????????
                   ?????????
                   ?????????
                   ?????????
                   ?????????




                AEWRNIXOL
                UTARENTIS
                BGASTUIOK
                RTWOPADRE
                IMONTRAQI 



                ARTXVMSBE
                IXKLRWTMO             
                USXTRKLBA  
                SEGVRKNIG
                FROPUHALB



                 NXHUDNCOR
                 SXJNBIMDN   
                 MJUDYAULE
                 MEGYABSUI
                 QWAEHOHIK



                MJIDXMEIW
                ADCNHOURT
                PLUOMERIN
                QTREYZAJO
                MRIEQAYTP



                ACHRTKHNU
                EHBCYRKTO
                UQXNHYLDI
                WASIEROUP
                MWASUNITY




It is

 The second option

The reason is:

 In the original set of grids, it reveals the vowels in their regular order if we highlight them within the grids (A,E,I,O) like so:
 

Leaving

 The final vowel U missing from the set and only the second option reveals this if we apply the same logic to it:
 

An interesting side note:

  If you look at the grids left right up down, the order of vowels always follows their order in the alphabet and the second option also is the only one which fits the bill for this pattern…


This is what happens when you do a puzzle and you're in a hurry :D Besides that, let's assume they all were in order, can you see why that one is defintely correct?

Yes you got it, that was the idea. Well done!

I was in a hurry because I started getting ptsd from when stiv just sniped me with the recent Roman numerals puzzle you made
